# Concatenate to an empty String in C?

Tags: c

```
void decode(char *str, int j)
{
int i;
char s[100]="";
i = strlen(str); 
//Print each uppercase character in the string
if(j<i)
{
    if(isupper(str[j]))
    {
        strcat(&str[j], s);
        j++;
        decode(str, j);
    }
    else
    {
        j++;
        decode(str, j);
    }
}
else
    printf("%s\n", s);  
}
```

This function is meant to print out only the uppercase characters from str (the arguement). But all it prints out currently is blank space. Something is clearly wrong with my understanding of strcat. I'm not sure if it works that way for the char array I declared at the top eg. will it still append to it even though it is declared as empty? If I take out the empty declaration for the char array it still prints empty. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Check out your argument order to `strcat`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth is right, check out the strcat definition: ``void strcat( char* dest, char* src )
{
     while (*dest) dest++;
     while (*dest++ = *src++);
}``

Comment: I had in the other way, and it still printed out just blank space for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if j< i you will print s, which is declared on the stack and is always empty when the function starts.
You may try to pass it to your decode function. Although it might be better to iterate over the string instead of using recursion.

Comment: I'm required to use recursion for this sadly. Also, J is 0, declared in main so it isn't redeclared during the recursive call, and i is always greater than 0. This is just to make sure it checks every character in the string.

Comment: OH I get it! Thanks very much I understand what I did wrong. I need to declare the other string outside so it isn't redeclared during the recursion. Thank you!

Comment: After declaring it outside the function and passing it as an argument, it prints the entire string and not just the uppercase.

Comment: The problem now is that strcat will not stop until it finds a string terminator. So it will copy the entire string and not only a single char.
Use strncat instead:
`strncat(&dest, &source, 1); // Concatenate only 1 char.`